# Why does the last element of a position vector can cause color to be solid

Tags: opengl-es, shader, webgl2

In the attached code, I try to draw a triangle using its texture coordinates. I'd expect the result to be in gradient color. but it turned out to be a solid color.

The reason is this line:

```
gl_Position = vec4(a_position.x, a_position.y, 0.0, 0.0);
```

the last number of position is 0.0. If I change it to 1.0, the color will be a gradient. why?

```js
var vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
// an attribute is an input (in) to a vertex shader.
// It will receive data from a buffer
in vec2 a_position;
in vec2 a_texcoord;
out vec2 v_texcoord;

// all shaders have a main function
void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = vec4(a_position.x, a_position.y, 0.0, 0.0);

  // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
`;

var fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;

// Passed in from the vertex shader.
 in vec2 v_texcoord;

// The texture.
// uniform sampler2D u_texture;

// we need to declare an output for the fragment shader
out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  //outColor = texture(u_texture, v_texcoord);
  outColor = vec4(v_texcoord.x, v_texcoord.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
`;


    const canvas = document.querySelector('#imageA');

    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

    gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;

    gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl,[vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource]);

    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
    var texcoordAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoord");

    // Create a vertex array object (attribute state)
    //var vao = gl.createVertexArray();

    // and make it the one we're currently working with
   // gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    // look up uniform locations
    //  var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");

    var positions = new Float32Array(
    [
     -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0, 
     -1.0,   -1.0, 
     1.0,   -1.0, 
    ]);

    var texCoords = new Float32Array(
    [
     0.0,  0.0,
     1.0,  0.0, 
     1.0,   1.0, 
     0.0,   1.0, 
    ]);
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);
    // Create a buffer
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    // Turn on the attribute

    // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    // Set Geometry.
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);


    var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

    // Set Geometry.
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordAttributeLocation);



    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
   // gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // turn on depth testing
   // gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // tell webgl to cull faces
   // gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE);



    // Bind the attribute/buffer set we want.
    //gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        test
    </title>
</head>

<canvas id="imageA" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Because of the [perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide). The normalized device coordinate is calculated by `gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w`. Since `gl_Position.w` is 0.0, the mathematical result of the division is infinit. Probably this is some kind of undefined behavior, the triangle gets very large and just a small snippet of it is on the viewport - the part in the center of the hypotenuse, with the orange color.

Comment: @Rabbid76: actually, the clipping will happen before the attempted divide by 0.. SInce this is basically drawing an infinitely big quad, the visible part on the screen will just be an infinitely tiny fraction of the actual gradient - a constant color.

Comment: @derhass Of course, the clipping `-w <= x, y, z <= w` -> `0.0 <= x, y, z <= 0.0`

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks, ya, I didn't think the rectangle got stretched. Thought the color was irreverent to the geometry... as the geometry appeared to be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indirectly pointed out the computation for varyings is as follows

```
result = (1 - t) * a / aW + t * b / bW
         -----------------------------
            (1 - t) / aW + t / bW
```

Where `aW` is the W that was set on `gl_Position.w` when the varying was as set to `a` and `bW` is the W that was set on `gl_Position.w` when the varying was set to `b`.

so setting `gl_Position.w` = 0 is going to have some issues

see

https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective-correct-texturemapping.html